# Benchmarking of models

Tags: heston, benchmark

Why do we need benchmarking adjustmenets for a model? Suppose, a trading desk is using Heston model for generating vol surface, then why do risk management uses various other models like IR Mean Reversion, other LVSV models etc to generate adjustments to be made to the Heston Model?